# Ajax Not Working Still Refresh Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to input `post`, then after pressing `enter` it should replace `<div id="mainPagePosts"></div>` with the new data without refreshing the page. However, after submitting `post`, it still refreshed the page, although I did get the data back in plain HTML.

I tried `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` but nothing worked.

**JQuery**

```
$("#homePagePostInputButton").keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $.ajax({
        url: "main/home",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({post:{"text": $("#homePagePostInput").val()}})
    }).done(function(result){
        updateMainPagePosts(result);
        removeTextFromInput("homePagePostInput");
    }).fail(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
  }
});

var updateMainPagePosts = function(posts){
  var div = document.getElementById("mainPagePosts");
  div.innerHTML = posts; 
};

var removeTextFromInput = function(input){
  var removeThis = document.getElementById(input);
  removeThis.value = ""; 
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-6 columns">
    <div class="card card-center">
        <div class="card-header card-post">
            <form action="/main/home" method="POST">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="homePagePostInput" name="post[text]" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" placeholder="What's on your mind, <%= user.firstName %>?">
                <input type="submit" id="homePagePostInputButton" style="display:none">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="mainPagePosts">
        //To be replaced with new data via AJAX
        <% include ../ajaxSnippets/mainHome %>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using `keypress` event on a button ?

Comment: @jerome As the button is hidden and the only way to submit is to press enter, so I use `keypress`?

Comment: i mean why do you assign the `keypress` event to a button?. Maybe you can change the `selector` value to `homePagePostInput`

Comment: Chhange `<input type="submit" ` to `<input type="button"`

Comment: @jerome Because if the user press `enter` on the button then it will trigger the ajax function?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, remove form post action

Secondly, change type="submit" in to type="button"

OR change

`$("#homePagePostInputButton").keypress`

to

`$(".card-header.card-post form").submit`

Comment: Tried that. It somehow works, but the page still refreshes as I can see the favicon changes to loading.

Comment: Do you have some other forms in this view?

Comment: There is a search bar at the top of the page. 
`<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
           <button class="btn btn-outline-light my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
</form> `

Comment: I think you need to check 2 form submit event and alert to know what form event raised.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is because you are posting your request and that is why your page gets refreshed. Do as suggested in the previous answer, or keep your HTML, but set a handler to the onSubmit event of the form and there use the preventDefault() method and return false from it. This way you are keeping the functionality if javascript is disabled, you will still post the form.

EDIT: Here is the code:

```
$("form").on('submit', function(e) {
    //you actually don't need e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Note: This will prevent **every** form in your page from submitting. So you may want to set an id of the form and select it via the id, instead of the form tag, like so:

```
$("#yourFormID").on(... etc.
```

Comment: `set a handler to the onSubmit event of the form and there use the preventDefault() method and return false from it` Sorry I don't quite understand this part. Could you show me how to do it?

Comment: Did you check the EDIT section in my answer?